# Github check for pull done on github repository

Tags: github, git-pull

Is there a way to check a github repo whether someone has pulled from it or not after adding that person as a collaborator? The repo is private if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

No (unless GitHub support has some internal logs about this).

The [event types](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/) exposed through the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) would include:

- [Download event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#downloadevent)
- [Fork event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#forkevent)
- [Pull Request event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent)

But nothing regarding a pull/fetch/clone.